# primary key condetions

Tags: sql

tricky question for me:
must the primary key (for a table ) a number ? or may be another type of data?

Comment: A primary key can be of any type, or indeed, a combination of types (multiple columns with different datatypes).

Comment: The primary key can be almost any type or  a combination of columns of almost any type.  Using an auto-incremented number is often a best-practice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the use of "almost" intrigues me, what types can't be primary key?

Comment: I think some big sized types cant be PK (or any index) is at least sql server

Comment: BLOB and CLOB are not very suitable for PK columns because they lack the full set of comparison operators (often declaring a PK automatically triggers creation of a clustered index, which is by default organized as a BTree, which requires '<' as well as "=" to be defined on the type, which it isn't).  Data types such as ROW MULTISET,which can occur in the result of queries, cannot ever be the type of a PK column because columns with such data type are typically prohibited in the db itself.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: that largely depends on the DBMS being used. Some are more restrictive than others

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

It not necessary to be number but integer(number) data types are the best to choice for primary key, followed by fixed-length character data types, but in the end you can choose whataver type of data depening of your case.

Answer (score 0):

Note that while SQL (the language) will put certain restrictions on what data type a column must have for being allowable in a PK (see my comment), the relational model of data imposes no such restrictions : the model is completely orthogonal to the type system, any column could have any data type, and the only prerequisite for being allowable in a candidate key is that the '=' equality operator is defined for the type of the column concerned, but that prerequisite is satisfied "by definition" because, well, a type for which one cannot test whether some given value of it is equal (i.e. the same value) to, well, the same value, is not a type.

Just mentioning this to draw your attention to the fact that "relational" is a seriously different thing than "SQL".